# best way to use conf.jocl

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, database-connection, quartz-scheduler

I have made a quartz thread application that is connecting to the database every 3 secs and do some checks and works on the database , but my database oracle admin is complaining of so many connection from it and tells me that it is always cause the database to hang up due to many connection .
so my question is what the best conf.jocl file to use and what modification should i do to mine?

**my conf.jocl code is :**

```
<object class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory" xmlns="http://apache.org/xml/xmlns/jakarta/commons/jocl">
   <object class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory">
      <string value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//url"/>
      <string value="username"/>
      <string value="password"/>
   </object>
   <!-- the next argument is the ObjectPool -->
   <object class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
      <object class="org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory" null="true"/>
      <int value="100"/> <!-- max active -->
      <byte value="1"/> <!-- when exhausted action, 0 = fail, 1 = block, 2 = grow -->
      <long value="30000"/> <!-- max wait -->
      <int value="-1"/> <!-- max idle -->
      <boolean value="false"/> <!-- test on borrow -->
      <boolean value="false"/> <!-- test on return -->
      <long value="-1"/> <!-- time between eviction runs -->
      <int value="-1"/> <!-- number of connections to test per eviction run -->
      <long value="-1"/> <!-- min evictable idle time -->
      <boolean value="false"/> <!-- test while idle -->
   </object>
   <object class="org.apache.commons.pool.KeyedObjectPoolFactory" null="true" />
   <string value="" null="true" /> <!-- validation query -->
   <boolean value="false"/> <!-- default read only -->
   <boolean value="true"/> <!-- default auto commit -->
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to few things:

1. `<int value="100"/>` - try lowering this value
2. It is possible that you are not closing / releasing connections to pool after use. Check it as well.

Comment: i am using rs.close();
   ps.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   
             closeConnection(conn);
             
   
  }